# Handling whether or not the user has already seen a popup, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I am a bit dumbfounded on how to achieve this properly. So you have an app that is getting regularly updated, and you show those new updates to the user (something like discord update popup and whats new and such). How do you handle whether or not the user has seen it? A more high level question that "local storage", I am well aware of that or storing it in a DB, but this doesn't seem 1) Scalable, 2) Easy to work with in the long run. Are there any JS libraries that can simplify the process, eg or do I have to manually track each update? If there are more updates or the user hasn't logged in a while

I hope I conveyed what I am working on properly. Would love to hear how it's usually done.

Comment: It's either local storage for not authenticated users or new table (maybe audit) where you have flags for all the different popups if there were shown to the customer or not

Answer (score 0):

> Q: have an app that is getting regularly updated, and you show those new updates to the user

A: **Service Worker** can help you .That support reacting to push message .And they provide `the Push API gives web applications the ability to receive messages pushed to them from a server, whether or not the web app is in the foreground, or even currently loaded, on a user agent.`

---

More detail about start up a service worker to send users a message . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API .

---

Finally I suggest you try **Workbox** , that is a library that bakes in a set of best practices when working with service workers.